# Android: Object contains class-ID

Tags: java, android, class, object

I have a class with a method, which returns a string. If I create an object and call the method, the object contains the ID of the class (com.ma.singhalja.testclass.greeting@99e92d)

```
package com.ma.singhalja.testclass;

import android.app.Application;


public class greeting extends Application{

    String sayHello(){
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

My main activity:

```
package com.ma.singhalja.testclass;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        greeting Hello = new greeting();
        Hello.sayHello();
        System.out.println(Hello);
    }
}
```

Log:
I/System.out: com.ma.singhalja.testclass.greeting@99e92d

Can anybody tell mehow to actually get the String "Hello" into the object? I have already tried to convert into a String with .toString().

Thank you!!

Comment: Not exactly sure, what you want, but maybe: `String response = Hello.sayHello(); System.out.println(response);`? Or overwrite the toString method in the object.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you don't print the good thing:

```
System.out.println(Hello.sayHello());
```

This will output `System.out.println(...)` the result of `Hello.sayHello()`, so `Hello!`.
If you do `System.out.println(Hello);`, you are trying to print a `Class`.

By the way:

- In general, class a capitalized `Greeting` not `greeting`
- Instantiate
  an `Application` is not good in Android. It's the platform that do
  that. Get the current instance with `getApplication()`
- `System.out.println(...)` it's not very Android-thing... You can use
  `Log.d(...)` for debugging